# How to extract form data's field name

Tags: go

My Go is acting as a router to direct url path to various projects.

What I've been trying to do is to get form data's field name,

Response from body:

```
----------------------------858963562546262475963074
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

james
----------------------------858963562546262475963074
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="account"

admin
----------------------------858963562546262475963074
```

I'm able to get value by doing g.PostForm(), But I'm trying to get name field(name,account) to determine whether if params is given but content is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you should parse your data as Multipart form data. Please check `multipart` package that should fit your need. [multipart package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#NewReader)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to related question.

Solution:

```
g.Request.ParseMultipartForm(128)
getForm := g.Request.MultipartForm
```

Retrieving value in "map":
getForm.Value